# Want to display overflow-x scroll at the bottom of my Trello like board

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs-directive

First of all, I'm not a designer but a developer, and because of my interest in learning some CSS (and now after trying a lot, because of the lack of a proper template :P ) I wanted to design a trello like board with its lists/columns and cards. It must be responsive.

I want the x-axis scrollbar to display at the bottom. Currently, it's sticking just under the columns content and following the column's size as more cards are created. I've already tryed to make each column extend to the bottom using height:100% without success. Also, this may be of interest, you can see some display:flex over there that worked for getting each column to display near the other instead of breaking to a new line when the container's width is reached. Don't know if this is preventing something with the column's height or what, I'm really confused with all this stuff.

I'm using:

- Bootstrap 3.3.7 (compatible with Angular 1.x)
- A template named Luxury (you can see some classes at the top of the following html, but isn't affecting the board)
- Angular pre 1.6 (the controllers, directives, services, templates approach)

Here's the CSS & HTML (all directives already rendered in an example):

```css
.playground-navbar {
    padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
    background-color: #11121b;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    padding: 1em;    
}

.board-view-container {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom: 3.3%;
}

.board-view-row
{
    height: 100%;
}

.playground-board-view {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.board-row {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.board-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.lists-container {
    display: flex;    
}

.list-column {
    padding: 1em;
    height: fit-content;
    display:inline-block;
}

.playground-list {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.list-title {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 200px;    
}

.list-title-input  {
    color: #000000;
}

.new-card {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: -1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new-card:hover {
    background-color: #6b6bb1;
    border-shadow: inset; 
}

.new-list {
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.431) !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.new-list:hover {
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.588) !important;
}
```

```html
<main style="height:100%">
   <a class="LC-logo" href="#/">
      <i class="icon-LClogo"></i>
      <!-- span class="text">Luxury</span> -->
   </a>
   <div class="content">
      <!-- ngView: -->
      <div ng-view="" id="playgroundView" class="ng-scope" style="">
         <div class="row ng-scope">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="navbar playground-navbar">
                  <h3 ng-bind="board.boardName" class="ng-binding">Frank's Board</h3>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="board-view-container ng-scope">
            <div class="row board-view-row">
               <div board="" board-data="board" edit-card-html="editCardHtml" id="board-view" style="height:100%;" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                  <div class="container playground-board-view">
                     <div class="row board-row">
                        <div board-lists="" lists="boardData.columns" members="boardData.team.members" class="lists-container ng-isolate-scope">
                           <!-- ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope" style="">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 1
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column">
                           <div class="playground-list new-list" ng-click="addNewList()">
                              <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                 <h5 style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left">
                                    Add new list...
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                                 </h5>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <footer class="pageFooter">
      <div class="btnContainer">
         <a class="gc-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon-handcrafted"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btnContainer">
         <a class="LC-logo" href="#/">
         <i class="icon-LClogo"></i>
         </a>
      </div>
   </footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

change both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to `visible` in `.board-row` I think is that what are you trying to do

```css
.playground-navbar {
    padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
    background-color: #11121b;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    padding: 1em;    
}

.board-view-container {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom: 3.3%;
}

.board-view-row
{
    height: 100%;
}

.playground-board-view {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.board-row {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    display: flex;
}

.board-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.lists-container {
    display: flex;    
}

.list-column {
    padding: 1em;
    height: fit-content;
    display:inline-block;
}

.playground-list {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.list-title {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 200px;    
}

.list-title-input  {
    color: #000000;
}

.new-card {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: -1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new-card:hover {
    background-color: #6b6bb1;
    border-shadow: inset; 
}

.new-list {
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.431) !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.new-list:hover {
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.588) !important;
}
```

```html
<main style="height:100%">
   <a class="LC-logo" href="#/">
      <i class="icon-LClogo"></i>
      <!-- span class="text">Luxury</span> -->
   </a>
   <div class="content">
      <!-- ngView: -->
      <div ng-view="" id="playgroundView" class="ng-scope" style="">
         <div class="row ng-scope">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="navbar playground-navbar">
                  <h3 ng-bind="board.boardName" class="ng-binding">Frank's Board</h3>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="board-view-container ng-scope">
            <div class="row board-view-row">
               <div board="" board-data="board" edit-card-html="editCardHtml" id="board-view" style="height:100%;" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                  <div class="container playground-board-view">
                     <div class="row board-row">
                        <div board-lists="" lists="boardData.columns" members="boardData.team.members" class="lists-container ng-isolate-scope">
                           <!-- ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope" style="">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 1
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column ng-scope">
                              <div class="playground-list list" ng-class="{ 'new-list' : list.newList, 'list' : !list.newList }">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div ng-click="list.title.editing = true">
                                       <h5 ng-show="!list.title.editing" style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left ng-binding">
                                          Column 2
                                       </h5>
                                       <input type="text" class="list-title-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 ? list.title.editing = false : ''" ng-blur="list.title.editing = false" ng-model="list.data" ng-show="list.title.editing" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr ng-show="!list.newList">
                                 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                    <ul dnd-list="list.items" class="list-group board-list">
                                       <!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items -->
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="new-card" ng-show="!list.newList" ng-click="addNewItem(this.list)">
                                    <p>Add new card...</p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg list-column">
                           <div class="playground-list new-list" ng-click="addNewList()">
                              <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
                                 <h5 style="text-transform: capitalize;" class="list-title pull-left">
                                    Add new list...
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                                 </h5>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <footer class="pageFooter">
      <div class="btnContainer">
         <a class="gc-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon-handcrafted"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btnContainer">
         <a class="LC-logo" href="#/">
         <i class="icon-LClogo"></i>
         </a>
      </div>
   </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem but let me make some advance by changing the problem to where do I set the overflow. Setting both overflows to visible is the same as not declaring them at all because visible are the default values, and therefore, the body scrollbar appears. This didn't work at first because of the template overflow property for the body, but after deleting the property, this kind of started to work. Not yet the solution because I don't want the scrollbar for the body but for border-row though. Thanks for your insight! (my vote isn't visible, I'm just a newbie in Stackoverflow!)

Comment: You just want the scroll for the border-row and you that the scroll stay fixed on bottom?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is that border-row's height isn't extended to the bottom and I can't find a way to extend it.